# XML Microsoft Word Document

Tags: xml, libreoffice, file-format, microsoft-word

I have a .xml file generated by someone with MS Word and I cannot manage to open it with LibreOffice or other app or change its format.

I tried to save a LibreOffice document as "Word 2003 xml" and able to reopened it later, so I think it might be created with Word 2007+ and seems LibreOffice cannot open it.

I reproduce first xml tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" 
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" 
xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" 
w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" 
xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: LibreOffice now has much much better support for Word documents

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. LibreOffice can open MS 2003 xml files because it used to use a simpler format back then. Newer MS Office use proprietary formats and binary blobs so your best bet is to go back to that someone and ask him/her politely to save it in MS Office 2003 format.

Comment: The sad thing here is that that's a document generated by a webapp of a government institution. Thanks. I'll try to install zero-cost-but-not-free Word Viewer under Wine.